# Running selenium test automatically

Tags: selenium

I have a problem with Selenium and can't get it to work.
What I want to do:
A customer of ours sends us a Selenium test case which shall be executed automatically in several locations and the time taken shall be recorded.
We want to use Selenium and Firefox Portable, because we want to make the tests completely independent of any user input and the installed software at the different locations.
So much for the starting conditions ;)
What we did so far:
The first version was completely written in Java, we exported the test case from the customer to Java with the Selenium IDE Plugin -> Export to Java WebDriver.
This cannot be done anymore, because the customer now uses some functions the WebDriver export does not support. And as we don't want to alter the test from the customer, Java export is no longer an option.
So for the first run we are using this command (any variables are set correctly):

```
java -jar selenium-2.33.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -port 5555 
-firefoxProfileTemplate "Firefox\Data\profile" -log logs\selenium_server.log 
-htmlSuite "*firefox" http://localhost:5555 Testsuite.html
logs\results-firefox-%curTimestamp%.html
```

This starts my preinstalled firefox, not the portable one. On the customers machine, no firefox is started whatsoever, because it is not installed. So I had to provide the path to the firefox instead, using the "custom" htmlSuite:

```
java -jar selenium-2.33.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -port 5555 
-firefoxProfileTemplate "Firefox\Data\profile" -log logs\selenium_server.log 
-htmlSuite "*custom %FF_DIR%\FirefoxPortable.exe" http://localhost:5555 Testsuite.html 
logs\results-firefox-%curTimestamp%.html
```

This does not work, as the Selenium Server cannot execute this command if run under Windows, which we do (see: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3274)
As comment #6 has some diffs, we patched the selenium Server standalone Jar and ran the test again. Now the browser could be started, but the test could not be run. After the first page loaded we get the error "Permission denied to access property 'document'".
A solution here suggests, a user-rights problem could be the cause and you should try the "chrome" htmlSuite (see: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/how-to-fix-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)
So we did:

```
java -jar selenium-2.33.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0-patched.jar 
-port 5555 -firefoxProfileTemplate "FirefoxPortable\Data\profile" 
-log logs\selenium_server.log -htmlSuite "*chrome %FF_DIR%\FirefoxPortable.exe" 
http://localhost:5555 Testsuite.html logs\results-firefox-%curTimestamp%.html
```

Notice our "patched" selenium and the "chrome" htmlSuite.
That didn't work, as well.
So, here in short the results:

- htmlSuite = firefox: the preinstalled Firefox is used, if installed, not the Portable one. In case, no FF is installed, the test fails altogether
- htmlSuite = chrome: the server cannot start the browser, as it tries to set EnvironmentVariables, which is not supported running Windows (see: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsProcessGroup.java#67 lines 67 following)
- htmlSuite = googleChrome: Google Chrome Portable can be started, but the Chrome browser cannot find some elements specified by the test, so we cannot use Chrome (altering the test is no option, as stated above)
- htmlSuite = iexplore: Internet Explorer starts, but then a JavaScript error appears, referencing a custom Profile created by Selenium, so the test does not work in IE, either
- htmlSuite = custom: the Portable Firefox is started (yeehaw), but does not have sufficient rights to execute the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have now decided to support the customer in installing Firefox on the machines to test, so we can use our batchfile without problems.

As for the bug in selenium look here (code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5554#c14), there is a link to a nightly build that does work (at least for us) with Firefox v23, which Selenium 2.33 does not.

Thanks for everyone who contributed, but I think my first approach can not be achieved the way I thought it could :(

Answer (score 5):

You may use a Continuous Integration System like Jenkins, or TeamCity to execute your tests automatically.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I don't think that will solve the problem, because it is no problem getting the test started initially but we don't have control over the way it is executed.
Additionally, I don't know how to control the jenkins from a batch file, so that would make the task more complicated.

Comment: Could you explain the flow you want to achieve? E.g. Bat->jenkins->selenium or something like that. You dont have to control Jenkins from a batch file because it has web gui, additionaly you could compile a selenium script starting the jenkins job or anything and execute it via batch file, but this is a strange way

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem.

Visit this link: http://www.townx.org/blog/elliot/dealing-self-signed-ssl-certificates-when-running-selenium-server-firefox

Point 9:
Delete everything in the directory except for the cert_override.txt and cert8.db files.

Hope it helps